Reference for Yoga Sutras
Can anyone suggest a simple and easy to understand translation(in Hindi or English) and explanation of Patanjali Yoga Sutras?

A lesser known but well written and easy to understsnd English translation of the Yoga Sutras: https://archive.org/details/yoga-sutras-of-patanjali-madhavacharya/page/2/mode/1up Overall, Patanjali's Yoga Sutras is an advanced book.
